# Selenium 2.37 XPath, finding an item in a context menu, then clicking that item a second time

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium 2.37, I can click the "Open" item in a context menu, when I search for it in two steps:

1. Find a few WebElement's by searching for the following XPath:

td[@class=\"dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel\" and " + "starts-with(@id,\"dijit_MenuItem_\")]

1. Then, for each WebElement in this List of WebElement's, I do 
   String s = we.getText();  if (s.equals("Open") == true) { ... }

This works fine.

My problem is when I do the above "in one step", by including the text search in the XPath:

td[@class=\"dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel\" and " + 
"starts-with(@id,\"dijit_MenuItem_\") and text()=\"Open\"]

In this case, I do find the "Open" entry in the context menu, and I can click on it.  So far, so good.  So for finding the Open entry ONCE, and clicking on it ONCE, both the above methods work fine.

The problem is that when I use the second method, then the NEXT time I want to bring up the context menu (for a different document) and click the Open menu item, the context menu appears.  BUT the mouse doesn't move down to the Open menu item, so the click never happens.

This is all during a single WebDriver run, so the result is that I can open one document (the first document I see), its context menu appears, the mouse moves to the Open context menu item, and clicks it.  But then (same WebDriver run), when I get to the second document, the right-click happens, and the context menu appears, BUT the mouse does NOT move down to the Open menu item, so the click never happens.

Of course, for now, I'm using the first method.  But I would really prefer to use the second method, since if everything (including the text() match) is in a single XPath expression, I can look for that element in a WebDriverWait.

It's as if the Open menu item is (somehow) destroyed, detached from the DOM, or whatever, when the more complex XPath is used to find it.

I only have this problem with items in CONTEXT menus.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You say that you can "select the Open entry", but not click it. What do you mean by select it? Is it highlighted in some way?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  By "select it", I meant that the running WebDriver code selected the Open menu item.  But now that I've tried it again, that was incorrect.  What ACTUALLY happens the second time is that the context menu appears.  BUT the mouse doesn't move down (in the context menu) to the Open item.  (This is different from the FIRST time, when the context menu appears, the mouse moves down to the Open item, and then clicks the Open item.)

Comment: I just updated the original question.  Thanks to forgivenson for pointing out my original error.

Comment: Timing issue is a common problem with Selenium. Meaning, the item you are trying to find with the xpath doesn't exist yet. Also, sometimes opening something twice will create it in the dom twice, and then you can't be sure it is finding the visible one, and not the old one that is hidden (but still in the dom). These are two common issues that I recommend looking into.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't send complete example of your problem but for what I understand you did not wait something to be loaded (specially if you do this on SPA it's some onClick binding). Try the first approach with hard-coded wait for one second, if it click then you need to find a way to check that the Open element have binded click. You can add some additional wait.until like:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

Also you can create some extended expected conditions which inject JavaScript to the browser and return is click is binded.